# Reordering file lines like other file (Unix)

Tags: unix, sorting

Is there a tool (or option for `sort`) which will re-order lines of a file so that they are ordered like a key in another file?

For example, I have a data file:

```
T01F01475558    30
T01F022B3A17    31
T01F022EEDFD    19
T01F026E0209    19
```

And another (sort "key" file):

```
T01F022EEDFD
T01F026E0209
T01F022B3A17
T01F01475558
```

Is there a way to sort the first file so that the first field is in the same order as the 2nd file? Each key is unique (no duplicates), and there are an equal number of lines in each file.

Is there a UNIX tool I don't know about that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Each key is unique (no duplicates), and there are an equal number of lines in each file.

This assumption is *very* important. If it holds then this command will do the job (in Bash):

```
paste <(nl key.file | sort -k 2 | cut -f 1) <(sort data.file) | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

Few tools use tab characters as separators. For this reason tabs mustn't occur in `key.file` (they may occur in `data.file` though). Sane entries in `key.file` should form a single column anyway, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Explanation:

1. `nl` adds a line number in front of every line of `key.file`; this makes the keys themselves move to the second column; `sort -k 2` sorts according to the second column, i.e. to the keys. The keys are then discarded by `cut -f 1`.
2. Another `sort` sorts `data.file`. Since the keys in front are unique, this default sorting is equivalent to sorting according to the sole keys.
3. The two results from `sort`-s are merged by `paste`. Without the first `cut` an example line would be:

   ```
        4  T01F01475558    T01F01475558    30
   ```

   The uniqueness of keys and equal number of them in both files are crucial. In effect the same keys from both `sort`-s meet in the same line leaving `paste`. Since you don't need duplicated keys to occupy the memory, the first `cut` was used as soon as possible. With it the real example line leaving `paste` is rather:

   ```
        4  T01F01475558    30
   ```
4. These lines are then sorted according to their numerical value. Line numbers from `nl` are in front, so this operation introduces the desired order.
5. At the end `cut` discards the first column, leaving the exact lines from `data.file`, yet in the desired order.

---

Alternatively you can try this (tested in Bash):

```
while IFS='' read -r ; do
   [ -n "$REPLY" ] && grep "^$REPLY " data.file
done <key.file
```

Note the code expects a space character after each key in `data.file`.

Pros:

- `key.file` may specify any number of keys, duplicate keys, nonexistent keys. In this case don't think "sorting", think "retrieving desired lines one by one".
- You can stream input (like stdin instead of `key.file`, just omit `<key.file`) and get the output on the fly.

Cons:

- `grep` will interpret keys as regular expressions, this may backfire. There is `grep -F` but in general you need `^` in the pattern.
- `read` is slow; spawning `grep` again and again is slow; opening `data.file` again and again is slow.